# sempiternus vs. æternus

Tags: word-comparison, adjective, ecclesiastical-latin, time, theology

What's the difference between *sempiternus* ("[always eternal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sempiternus#Etymology)") and *æternus* ("eternal")?

Does *æternus* refer to creatures (e.g., angels and human souls) that were created in time but will always exist from the moment of their creation? Does *sempiternus* only describe God, [Who is absolutely eternal](https://isidore.co/aquinas/Compendium.htm#5) and uncreated?

Comment: I think you have it backwards. In scholastic Latin, sempiternal describes something with an infinite future, but a finite past. Eternal describes something with an infinite past as well. So far as I know, the scholastics were the first to distinguish these terms. In earlier times, they were mere synonyms.

Comment: @Figulus Why not "_semiternus_" (_semi-_ = half), then?

Comment: Obviously, I'm just speculating, but *semiternus* does not seem to be a pre-existing word, whereas *sempeternus* is classical.

Comment: @Figulus I mean: Why isn't _sempiternus_'s etymology _semi-_ + eternal?

Comment: Aquinas doesn't seem to distinguish *sempiternus* and *aeternus* in a principled way, as far as I can tell from a corpus search: both can be used to describe God. He does have an interesting article in *Summa Theologiae* I, q. 10, a. 5 that goes into the difference between "aevum," "tempus," and "aeternitas." There, he uses the term *aeviternus*, and I've frequently heard "aeviternity" brought up--less so "sempiternity." But perhaps it's a later distinction.

Comment: @brianpck [_Summa Theologica_ I q. 10 a. 5](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP010.html#FPQ10A5THEP1) "The difference of aeviternity (_ævum_) and time"

Comment: @brianpck Ah! I had forgotten *aeviternus*. Perhaps my faulty memory has confused *aeviternus* with *sempiternus*. That would explain why I can't find a reference to back up my comment. I hereby retract it.

Comment: The etymology of these words is interesting. Judging from what I can find in the dictionaries, *aeternus* seems to be a contraction of *aeviternus*. *Aeviternus* is from *aevitas* plus the *-rnus* suffix (*hodiernus*, *hesternus*, etc.) *Sempiternus* is a compound of *semper* + *aeternus*. So if *aeternus* means forever, does *sempiternus* mean forever and ever? An intensified synonym? Seems likely. I'm not sure that such antique etymologies have much bearing on much later developments of technical jargon, though.

Answer (score 2):

St. Thomas Aquinas takes the adjectives [*sempiternus*](http://www.corpusthomisticum.org/it/index.age?results.pageSize=50&text=Deus%20sempiternus) and [*æternus*](http://www.corpusthomisticum.org/it/index.age?results.pageSize=50&text=Deus%20aeternus) as synonyms, e.g.:

[*Contra Gentiles* lib. 2 cap. 31](https://isidore.co/aquinas/ContraGentiles2.htm#31) n. 5:

> *Deus sempiternus est*

[*Contra Gentiles* lib. 1 cap. 15](https://isidore.co/aquinas/ContraGentiles1.htm#15) n. 5:

> *Est igitur Deus æternus*

St. Jerome's *Vulgate* uses *sempiternus* to describe God (and doesn't use *æternus* at all), e.g.:

[Is. 40:28](https://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=27&ch=40&l=28-#x):

> *Deus sempiternus Dominus*

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think you need to provide more evidence. Obviously it is not always the case that X and Y are synonyms if "S is X" and "S is Y' are both true: it's necessary but insufficient. I think you are also not answering your own question as stated: it's quite possible that there is a difference in other authors.

Comment: @brianpck Yes, I agree. The first quote in context is "_si Deus sempiternus est_" (conditional, so perhaps noncommittal).